# Set focus on Jquery datepicker on datepicker close, without opening datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to set focus on input of datepicker, after datepicker closes, but without opening it again.

Does anyone have a solution to this wicked request?

I have tried something like this, but finally I cant get it to work for IE9.

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
               showDatepicker = false;

               if (detectIE()) {
                 $(this).focus();
               } else {
                 setTimeout(function() {
                   $(this).focus();
                 })
               } 
            },
            beforeShow: function() {
                if (!showDatepicker) {
                    showDatepicker = true;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried adding this.focus(); on onClose?

Comment: I am doing it. $("#" + id) is actually $(this). I copied it from a function, and forgot to change it. Updated now.

Comment: this.focus() is working fine in IE9, tested!

Comment: yes, it opens the datepicker, but that is not what I want. I want it to set focus on close, without opening datepicker.

Comment: Use a flag to control if the datepicker should be shown again on focus.
Re-enable the same on Blur event.

Comment: Does it work in other browsers than IE9? Please update your question to make that more clear, and if it is only IE9 causing the problem I would recommend you to add the internet-explorer-9 tag.