# Bootstrap datepicker: Focus without opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker, onfocus

I'm using a bootstrap datepicker and jQuery validate.  I have jquery validate set to focus on the input when the field is empty & required.

With bootstrap datepicker however, the focus event causes the calendar to open.  Which is not ideal in my situation.  I'm wondering if there is a way to focus, but pass through a preventDefault or something like that?

I made a jsfiddle.  Basically, is it possible to click the button to focus on the element, but not have the calendar open? https://jsfiddle.net/a2gkpxuh/ The primary purpose of the focus is to scroll the page so the user can see the required element.

```
$("#myButton").click(function () {
   //Some code to prevent default here?  Possibly disable datepicker before .focus event
   $("#myDatePicker").focus();
});
```

I guess one possible solution would be to disable the datepicker, then do my jQuery.validate(), then re-enable the datepicker.  I feel like there's a better way though...

FYI Here is a similar question: [Set focus on Jquery datepicker on datepicker close, without opening datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239135/set-focus-on-jquery-datepicker-on-datepicker-close-without-opening-datepicker)

Comment: I don't see jQuery Validate anyplace in your jsFiddle.  If you have a question, it's up to you to properly demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I thought I was simplifying in the fiddle by making a button which mimicked jQuery Validate doing a .focus().  I was able to get a good answer immediately.  Maybe I should remove the jQuery Validate tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just hide the datepicker after the focus:

```
$("#myButton").click(function () {
    $("#myDatePicker").focus();
  $("#myDatePicker").datepicker('hide');
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly.  The hide event happens so fast that you never actually see it pop up on the screen due to the focus

Answer (score 2):

Just an add to Maxwell_Orr that will prevent the user from popping the datepicker.

you could do something like this:

```
$('.default-date-picker').datepicker({
  format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
  autoclose: true
});

$("#myButton").click(function () {
    $("#myDatePicker").focus();
    $("#myDatePicker").datepicker('hide');
});

$("#myDatePicker").click(function () {
    $("#myDatePicker").focus();
});
```